# oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver. IO Error: IO Error Genearal SSLEngine problem when trying to connect liquibase to Oracle RDS

Tags: java, oracle, maven, amazon-rds, liquibase

I have developed liquibase maven project which updates the Oracle RDS Database schema through changelog.sql file.
It runs successfully in the local environment but when I try to deploy this on bamboo in the Development environment SSL connection gets failed with the below message.

```
[Error] liquibase.exeception.DatabaseException: liquibase: Connection could not be created to jdbc:oracle:thin@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCPS)(HOST=xyz.us-east1.rds.amazon.com)(PORT=2145))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=OYKXXX1X)))?useSSL=true&requireSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=true with driver oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver. IO Error: IO Error General SSLEngine problem, connect lapse 20 ms., Authentication lapse 0ms.
```

Below is my liquibase.properties shell file

```
cat <<eof > ${bamboo_result_artifactId}-{bamboo_result_versin}/src/main/resources/liquibase.properties
driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
url=jdbc:oracle:thin@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCPS)(HOST=xyz.us-east1.rds.amazon.com)(PORT=2145))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=OYKXXX1X)))?useSSL=true&requireSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=true
username=xyz1234
password=ABC_22323_XYZ
changeLogFile=src/main/resources/db/chagelog/db.changelog-master.yml
eof
```

I have hardcoded the username and password to test the connection of liquibase with the Oracle RDS database.
Requested to please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue looks in your URL. Kindly check if you have entered the correct url in the liquibase.properties file. Usage should look like this:

> JDBC:oracle:thin:@{host}[:{port}]/{database}

In your case, your URL may look like this:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin@xyz.us-east1.rds.amazon.com:2145/OYKXXX1X?useSSL=true&requireSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=true
```

Comment: I tried using the Oracle Aws RDS link in your format but the same issue. Somehow I want to set the certificate path that I am currently not getting

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I need to change the structure of code from Maven liquibase to Spring-boot liquibase project and I was able to establish liquibase to RDS SSL connection successfully.

```
package com.lmig.grs.springliquibase;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Objects;

@Configuration
public class SSLConfiguration {

    public static final String JAVAX_NET_SSL_TRUST_STORE = "javax.net.ssl.trustStore";
    public static final String JAVAX_NET_SSL_TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD = "javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword";
    public static final String JAVAX_NET_SSL_TRUST_STORE_TYPE = "javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType";
    public static final String JAVAX_NET_SSL_KEY_STORE = "javax.net.ssl.keyStore";
    public static final String JAVAX_NET_SSL_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD = "javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword";
    public static final String JAVAX_NET_SSL_KEY_STORE_TYPE = "javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType";
    public static final String ORACLE_NET_SSL_SERVER_DN_MATCH = "oracle.net.ssl_server_dn_match";
    public static final String JKS = "JKS";
    public static final String PASSWORD = "changeit";
    public static final String KS_FILE_NAME = "clientkeystore";

    @PostConstruct
    private void configureSSL() throws URISyntaxException {
        URL clientKeystoreUrl = SSLConfiguration.class.getClassLoader().getResource(KS_FILE_NAME);
//        LOGGER.info(String.format("Classloader.clientkeystore [%s]", clientKeystoreUrl));
        final File tempKeystore = new File((Objects.requireNonNull(clientKeystoreUrl)).getFile());

        System.setProperty(JAVAX_NET_SSL_TRUST_STORE, tempKeystore.getAbsolutePath());
        System.setProperty(JAVAX_NET_SSL_TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD, PASSWORD);
        System.setProperty(JAVAX_NET_SSL_TRUST_STORE_TYPE, JKS);
        System.setProperty(JAVAX_NET_SSL_KEY_STORE, tempKeystore.getAbsolutePath());
        System.setProperty(JAVAX_NET_SSL_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD, PASSWORD);
        System.setProperty(JAVAX_NET_SSL_KEY_STORE_TYPE, JKS);
        System.setProperty(ORACLE_NET_SSL_SERVER_DN_MATCH, "true");
    }
}
```